# Unable to identify the symbol in schematic

Tags: schematics, symbol

In my job I came across reading a customer schematic. I am facing trouble in identifying the marked part of the schematic, which is connected at the pins of `uUSB` Interface Controller.

It seems like a fuse but not very sure of the symbol, as its confidential, unfortunately the engineer did not give a part name also. Any way, it doesn't effect the design but I am eager to know about it out of interest.

The design is of a mobile phone.

[image: Schematic containing the unknown symbol]

Comment: Maybe a ferrit bead, I am not sure.

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Maybe ask the designer?

Comment: Can you share the part number of the IC with the BOOT and JIG pin?

Comment: @BattleHamster its SM5504, any way you will not find even if you google. as its confidential. kindly let me know if you did :)

Comment: I would also guess it's a ferrite bead

Comment: Is it a switching IC for mobile phones? If it is, I did find something but not datasheet.

Comment: I have to guess as well. But for me it looks like a removable part of the wire (I usualy use a 0R resistor for that)

Comment: I think @Botnik is right since two wires are connected to JIG. Maybe some sort of testing/measurement connection.

Comment: Just found this recent question with a schematic containing the same symbol, though it's not the topic there...   http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163705/pin-of-micro-usb-connector-in-smartphone

Comment: any way got it confirmed with designer, its a shorting jumper kind of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not get the same signal i.e JIG_ON_N.

Actually it is shutdown or reset button that requires a short push (push button) that is short this two wires. Search on Eagle

[image]

Some times, schematic editor softwares using strange symbols that are not standard for industry.